# JAVAFX: Location not set error when previously it was working perfectly

Tags: java, xml, maven, javafx, illegalstateexception

This is my project structure:

[image: This is my project structure]

I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.` on these lines in the Window.java class.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/LoginWindow.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load(); // this line is getting the error
```

10 minutes ago everything was working fine but then I moved all the packages to a new project where I was using maven, worked out the dependencies, renamed all packages to be the same as the previous project, but when I'm trying to run I get the above error. Any wonder why?

The code in my fxml files is correct, no errors. The classes have no errors.

EDIT: I also tried the static method for loading the fxml file and got the same error.

EDIT: I got it working by adding this in my build section in `pom.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.*</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

**Thanks to @James_D for the help!**

Comment: Check the build folder. Probably the FXML files have not been deployed along with the class files.

Comment: @James_D you are right. The fxml package is the only one missing. I tried rebuilding the whole project but that folder is still not building.

Comment: If you're using Maven for the build, then you need to check the build settings in the pom.xml file. I don't know Maven very well...

Comment: Me neither. 
I'll try to look into it

Comment: Again, assuming you are using maven for the build process, you could [edit] the question to include your pom.xml file and add a maven tag.